# Mailgun, Post Incoming Data in App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, routes, mailgun

Having trouble accessing POST params using Mailgun. Here's my route.rb and incoming_controller.rb files.  Basically, I want to update my view with the data from the incoming emails.

```
post :incoming, to: 'incoming#create'
```

Controller

```
class IncomingController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]

  def index
  end

  def create
    puts "INCOMING PARAMS HERE: #{params}"
    @subject = Incoming.new(params[:subject])
    @subject.save

    @sender = Incoming.new(params[:from])
    @sender.save
    @body = Incoming.new(params[:'body-plain'])
    @body.save

    head 200
  end
end
```

I can see the request as it's coming into heroku (via heroku logs), but it's not being stored. I also need to test it locally

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the params in your create action as follows:

```
sender = params["sender"]
body_plain = params["stripped-text"]
```